# Entity Framework Code Based Migration not working after upgrade from EF 4.3 to EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

We are intensively used Entity Framework 4.3 with a code first .NET 4.0 based project within several sites, everything works smooth, fast and bugless, but to enable the last speed improvements made by the Entity Framework team we are now planning an upgrade to EF6 and .NET 4.5

After amending a couple of using clauses (due to the namespaces changes in the latest releases) everything seems to working properly if starting with an empty db, but trying to open an existing customer database will get an exception as soon as the Context() construction happens, apparently something is wrong with the code based migration.

My code based migration configuration is the following:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
   public Configuration()
   {
       AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
       AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
   }
}
```

With this application initialiser (program.cs)

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new UniversalDbConnection();
```

Having UniversalDbConnection declared as

```
class UniversalDbConnection : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string givenString)
    {
        switch (Preferences.DatabaseVendor)
        {
            case ConnectionPreset.PostgreSQL:
                return new PgSqlConnection(Preferences.ConnectionString);
            default:
                SqlConnectionFactory factory = new SqlConnectionFactory(Preferences.ConnectionString);
                return factory.CreateConnection(Preferences.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately an exception claiming:
**The object 'FK_StockTests_FormulaSteps_Step_Id' is dependent on column 'Step_Id'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Step_Id failed because one or more objects access this column** arises

Comment: I do not know ehy this is happening, it seems like Migrations is trying to drop a FK. Maybe the name changed from what is in the database and what is in your model? You can look the script that it is trying to execute running `Update-Database -script` on the Package Manager Console, this could help you to find what is happening here.

Comment: It didn't change, not a bit! I guess it must be some convention change in EF...

Comment: I've had a similar problem when upgrading from 4.3 to 6.  I don't use code migrations (all DB changes performed manually), and after the upgrade, code is failing trying to create SQL objects that already exist, even though I have not explicitly enabled migrations.  The only way I am able to prevent it is by adding "Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null)" at App startup.